# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor de un botón para almacenarlo en un array cada vez que se da click?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor de un botón para almacenarlo en una variable tipo array cada vez que se da click?

El proceso que he intentado hacer es este, pero cada que doy click, el array siempre tiene datos nuevos y no los almacena cada que doy click.

Ayuda por favor

**Esto es lo que he intentado hacer para almacenar en una variable el valor del boton cada que doy click**

```
$(document).on('click', '#eliminarMetros', function () {
                let metros = [$(this).attr('value')]
                let concat = metros.concat()
                console.log(concat)
                
})
```

**Este es el botón**

Los datos vienen de la base de datos, tengo varios botones de estos por lo que al eliminar osea al dar clic en este botón se vayana almacenando los valores en un array cada que doy clic o elimino una fila en este caso de una tabla.

```
<td><a href="#" id="eliminarMetros" value="" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon" type="button"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>
```

Comment: puedes agregar el codigo html del boton???

Comment: Solo saca tu variable metros fuera del metodo y utilizas `var metros=[]`, y lo llenas con `metros.push($this).attr('value'));`

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta @FranciscoNúñez.

Comment: @JhoubertRincon lo hice y recibo estos arrays por separado Array [ "36" ]Array [ "35" ], pero quisiera que esos valores se metan en un solo array por ejemplo Array["36", "35"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente que en tu caso parece que funciona

```
let metros = []
    $(document).on('click', '#eliminarMetros', function () {
                
    metros.push($(this).attr('value'))
    console.log(metros);
                
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo un ejemplo usando botones con la misma `class`, básicamente lo que ocurre con tu ejemplo es que al declarar el `array` dentro de la función le borras los valores que tenga y le asignas el valor del botón al que se haya hecho clic, si pones la declaración del `array` afuera de la función, debería mostrar lo que buscas, quedaría algo así:

```js
var valores = [];

$('.eliminarMetros').on('click', function () {
                valores.push($(this).val()); 
                console.log(valores);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="1" id="btn1" class="eliminarMetros">1</button>
<button value="2" id="btn2" class="eliminarMetros">2</button>
<button value="3" id="btn3" class="eliminarMetros">3</button>
```

Comment: Gracias compa, funciona perfecto cuando estoy en un modal  y le doy click pero cuando me salgo de ese modal y entro a otro los arrays se siguen sumando, que podría hacer para que se limpie el arrays anterior y se almacenen nuevos arrays ???

Comment: En ese caso que podría hacer ???

Comment: Puedes agregar otro evento ligado al `modal`, para que en cuanto el modal se muestre limpie el array, algo así: `$( "#modal" ).on('shown', function(){ aqui el ejemplo });`. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Haciendo push a una variable.

```
let arraydeMetros = [];

$(document).on('click', '#eliminarMetros', function () {
   let metros = $(this).attr('value');
   arraydeMetros.push(metros);
   console.log(arraydeMetros);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que hacer algo así:

```js
    var metros = 0;
    $(document).on('click', '.metros', function () {
                    metros += parseFloat($(this).attr('value'));
                    console.log('Total de metros: ' + metros);
    })
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>


<a href="#" id="eliminarMetros" value="1" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon metros" type="button"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> 1</a>
<a href="#" id="eliminarMetros" value="2" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon metros" type="button"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> 2</a>
<a href="#" id="eliminarMetros" value="3" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon metros" type="button"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> 3</a>
<a href="#" id="eliminarMetros" value="4" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon metros" type="button"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> 4</a>
<a href="#" id="eliminarMetros" value="5" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon metros" type="button"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> 5</a>
<a href="#" id="eliminarMetros" value="6" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon metros" type="button"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> 6</a>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Tienes que adaptarlo a tu necesidad.**

para resetar la variable al moverte entre los modals tendrias que hacer algo como:

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    metros = 0;
})
```

con delegación de eventos:

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal','Aqui va el Selector', function(e) {
    metros = 0;
})
```

Comment: Gracias compa pero necesito meterlo en un array, los datos si se concatenan pero esta unidos.

Comment: @DavidPaucar ya hice una actualización para que veas como funciona

Comment: @DavidPaucar con esto tendrás el total de metros eliminados por cada fila que vayas quitando.

Comment: Gracias compa, funciona perfecto cuando estoy en un modal y le doy click pero cuando me salgo de ese modal y entro a otro los arrays se siguen sumando, que podría hacer para que se limpie el arrays anterior y se almacenen nuevos arrays ???

Comment: tendrias que resetear el valor de la variable cuando un modal hace shown.

Comment: @DavidPaucar ya te agregue el reset cuando te mueves entre modal... tienes que adaptarlo...

Comment: Gracias compa lo voy a intentar

Comment: @DavidPaucar ya revisaste el post lo actualice agregando es parte.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112044/discussion-between-david-paucar-and-francisco-nunez).

Answer (score -1):

Logré hacerlo de esta manera y funcionó

```
let metros = []
    $(document).on('click', '#eliminarMetros', function () {
                
    metros.push($(this).attr('value'))
    console.log(metros);
                
})
```